# Running applet from html page

Tags: html, applet

I have made a simple Applet which simply invokes a ant target thorugh batch file on click of button. To do this i am using

```
ExecTask exec = new ExecTask();
exec.setExecutable("run.bat");
Commandline.Argument arg = exec.createArg();
arg.setValue("-buildfile D:/cloudengine/Applet/build.xml");
exec.execute();
```

When i run this from eclipse it works properly. But my requirement is to run this from a html page so i have created a simple html with applet tag

```
<APPLET ALIGN="CENTER" CODE="HtmlAntTest.class" WIDTH="800" HEIGHT="500"></APPLET>
```

But in browser's java console i get below exception on click of button

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-2" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.<init>(ExecTask.java:72)
.
.
.
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.util.PropertyPermission file.encoding read)
```

Any pointers would be of great help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to grant additional rights to the applet. It is all explained in detail here:
http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/appA.html

Comment: Thanks das. Got some basics of security from given link. One more question, why this simple applet need access to desktop...now its giving me an exception java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.io.FilePermission C:\Documents and Settings\admin\Desktop read)

Comment: @Sakhi Well I could only speculate about that ... Maybe its just the current working directory and ant tries to write a log file there. You should try to grant the necessary permission and check what changed ... maybe you can tweak your ant target ... as I said: speculations ;)

Answer (score 0):

As das_weezul commented, the applet will require elevated privileges to do this.  While changing policy files is one way to achieve that, it is error prone and impractical for deployment.

To get an applet trusted at time of deployment, it will be necessary to:

1. Put the classes in a Jar file (see [Packaging Programs in JAR Files](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/) for details).
2. Digitally sign the Jar file (see [Signing and Verifying JAR Files](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/signindex.html) for details).
3. Get the end user to OK the code when prompted to trust it.

It takes a little time to set up code signing in a build file, but once done correctly it can be forgotten.